# How to Reorder Formal Class Spatial Polygons

Tags: r, rgdal, r-sp

I'm looking for a way to re-order a set of Formal Class Spatial Polygons using

I'm using US Census data (Limited to Texas) and want to create 33 polygons out of different county combinations.

```
library(tmap)
library(maptools)
library(ggplot2)
library(rgeos)
library(sp)
library(mapdata)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

# Download the map of texas and get the LMAs boundaries
#   Download shape
f <- tempfile()
download.file("http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2010/gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.zip", destfile = f)
unzip(f, exdir = ".")
US <- read_shape("gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.shp")

#   Select only Texas
Texas <- US[(US$STATE %in% c("48")),]


#   Load the LMA append data
LMAs = read.table('LMA append data.csv',header=T, sep=',')

#   Append LMA data to Texas shape
Texas$FIPS <- paste0(Texas$STATE, Texas$COUNTY)
Texas <- append_data(Texas, LMAs, key.shp = "FIPS", key.data = "FIPS")
Texas <- Texas[order(Texas$LMA),]

#   Create shape object with LMAs polygons
Texas_LMA <- unionSpatialPolygons(Texas, IDs=Texas$LMA)
```

I've tried converting Texas_LMA into a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame with

```
#   Create shape object with LMAs polygons
Texas_LMA <- unionSpatialPolygons(Texas, IDs=Texas$LMA)
spp <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(Texas_LMA,data=matrix(1:33,nrow=33,ncol=1))
```

But that hasn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. But I think this is what you are after:

```
library(raster)
f <- tempfile()  download.file("http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2010/gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.zip", destfile = f)
unzip(f, exdir = ".")
US <- shapefile("gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.shp")
Texas <- US[(US$STATE %in% c("48")),]
LMAs = read.csv('LMA append data.csv')  
Texas$FIPS <- paste0(Texas$STATE, Texas$COUNTY)
```

You did not provide the LMA data, so guessing a bit from here:

```
Texas <- merge(Texas, LMAs, by="FIPS")  
Texas_LMA <- aggregate(Texas, by='LMA')
```

Comment: That gets it into a SpatialPolygonDataFrame and it lets me re-order the polygons to be in the order I need. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
shapefilename[order(shapefilename$column_name),]
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation as to why this is a solution to OP's problem. Code only answers are discouraged on SO as they do not help OP or future visitors of the site.

Comment: He needs to reorder polygon shapefile called "shapefilename" by a specific column (column_name). This command do It. Understood?